# Getting color as a JSON input to a d3 bullet chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am following the following D3 bullet chart example, trying to modify it a bit so that the different colors of the ranges are also included in the JSON: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/07/introduction-to-bullet-charts-in-d3js.html. The reason for the change is that I need the colors to be dynamic and depend on various things.

This exists one other place in the forum, but old and unsolved. I should add that I am a total newbie to d3, and don't have a lot of JavaScript experience in general.

Here is the JSON I use. "rangecolor" will in the future be an array of different colors, as there are several ranges, but for simplicity I attempt only with one color to begin with.

```
  {
    "title":"Memory Used",
    "subtitle":"MBytes",
    "ranges":[256,512,1024],
    "rangecolor": "red",
    "measures":[768],
    "markers":[900]
  }
```

Now, getting an idea of how to use it, I looked at the working example for title:

```
  var title = svg.append("g")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + height / 2 + ")");

  title.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.title; });
```

The problem is that I cannot get the following to work:

> ```
> d3.selectAll(".bullet .range.s0")
>   .style("fill", function(d) { return d.rangecolor; });
> ```

The following **does** work:

```
d3.selectAll(".bullet .range.s0")
  .style("fill", function(d) { return "red"; });
```

And I can also extract the rangecolor value to the title:

```
  title.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.rangecolor; }); //works - title is now "red"
```

My approach might be misguided, so any help on how to best include color ranges to the JSON and using it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you **bind** the data to that class, whatever it is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you select all bullets, there is no data bound to them so `d` is `undefined` here:

```
d3.selectAll(".bullet .range.s0")
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d.rangecolor; });
```

Why? You did not perform a data join like this:

```
d3.selectAll('.something').data(somethingData)
  .style('fill', function (d) { // d is defined });
```

You should wonder why it works for the title on the contrary. This is because when you do this:

```
var title = svg.append("g");
```

`title` inherits data from the `svg` selection. See [Mike Bostock explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10130018/5222444). In fact I was myself not aware of this behaviour, I prefer performing data joins explicitly.

I don't know the overall structure of your code, but you might apply you rangecolor properties with data inheritance (as for title) or refactor to use explicit data joins.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am too new to all of this, so I need to do some research to understand it. 

My code is as in the example, all I am doing is adding the color in the JSON and trying to make it work. So the title stuff is from the example as well.

Comment: I solved it by using d3.selectAll(".bullet .range.s0").data(data)

I must admit I don't understand what I am doing here, but I will study up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have talked with some experienced developers that state that the tutorial I am following is not a good one. It is a bit messy, and I am trying to find something cleaner. Troubleshooting has been difficult in this regard, and

The exact issue presented here was solved by using d3.selectAll(".bullet .range.s0").data(data).